# Ansible nxos_interface module:

Tags: ansible

I am a network engineer and new to Ansible automation, I am trying configure the Nexus switch interfaces as mentioned in the play book, I don't face issue getting result from ios_command module but issues is happening from ios_config module, I don't understand what is the issue, please help me, 
I have pasted the playbook and error logs below:

```yaml
---
---
- name: configure ethernet interface
  hosts: nx-os

  tasks:
    - name: filter hostname
      ios_command:
        commands: "show run | inc hostname"

      register: output

    - name: configure interfaces
      nxos_interface:
          - name: "{{ item.name }}"
            admin_state: up
            duplex: full
            speed: auto

      with_items:
         - name: Ethernet1/41
         - name: Ethernet1/42
      when: "'nx-os' in output.stdout[0]"
```

Error:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The TRANSFORM_INVALID_GROUP_CHARS settings is set to allow bad characters in group names by default, this will change, but
still be user configurable on deprecation. This feature will be removed in version 2.10. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/root/ansible/bkrishna/configure_interface.yml': line 12, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Admin down an interface
      ^ here
```

Comment: Hi rkbalaguru, welcome to S.O. You have failed to mention your ansible version, and whether this has ever worked for you, or only recently stopped working, and whether there are any other `ios_config:` tasks that do work for you

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, Thanks for your response, my ansible version is 2.9.2, it looks like there is an another module for nx-os for port configuration, since i used ios_config it did not work, i have changed the play, but still it's not working,

Comment: The YML you provided doesn't contain the line from error. There is no such step `- name: Admin down an interface`. Please post proper config and/or error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty explicit:

> ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: `<class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>`

there are no ansible modules that accept a **list** as their main configuration shape, although some do accept lists for individual keys

You will want this instead:

```yaml
- name: configure interfaces
  nxos_interface:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    admin_state: up
    speed: auto
  with_items:
  - # as you had before ...
```

Comment: it's working after i removed - from key value pair, Thanks mdaniel for your help.